# How to get IE8 Developer Tools to show me the line number of the Javascript error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I've got an Angular app, lots of javascript.  I load it up in IE8, and get an error that I'm not getting in other browsers. I open the Developer Tools, but it gives me only generic message.  No stack trace, no line number.  Here's a screen shot.

[image]

Is there something I can do to get the error location?

Comment: Try opening the site in a newer version of IE that does support line numbers, then set it to IE8 rendering mode?

Comment: I went to IE9 and didn't get the line number but I got more information about the property/method that was being called so that I could search for it. 'hasOwnProperty'

Answer (score 2):

If you expand/scroll that part of Dev Tools you will see the line number and the source file where it happened. E.g.

[image]

Moreover - clicking on that line will bring you directly to the source.

Comment: I've clicked all over that message.  Nothing happens.  You have IE8?

Comment: Yes the above screenshot is from IE8, I just went to jsfiddle.net as a test - it threw all kinds of errors (displayed above with respective links and line numbers)

Comment: Perhaps the code of your app generates its own custom exceptions? Also, do you have "Disable Script Debugging" unchecked in Advanced IE8 options?